# 2 Reserved IP's for a VM in Azure

Tags: azure

I am trying to assign to a second Reserved IP to a Cloud Service in Azure using:

> Set-AzureReservedIPAssociation -ReservedIPName somereservedipname -ServiceName someservicename

but i get this error message:

> Set-AzureReservedIPAssociation : BadRequest: The deployment with name 'somename' already has a reserved Ip 
>   'someip' in VirtualIp 'someVIP'

I thought Azure now supported multiple Reserved VIP's on Cloud Service and VM's?
I have also followed this document and still the Reserved IP does not work correctly: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/load-balancer-multivip/

The IP address attached to the endpoint created from this document changed, causing lots of access problems for users.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it! So Set-AzureReservedIPAssociation doesn't seem to work but you can use:

> Add-AzureVirtualIP

then associate it to an endpoint using:

> Get-AzureVM -ServiceName myService -Name myVM1 | Add-AzureEndpoint -Name myEndpoint -Protocol tcp -LocalPort 8080 -PublicPort 80 -VirtualIPName Vip2 | Update-AzureVM

and finally create the reserved ip by using:

> New-AzureReservedIP.

Using common parameters that associate the IP's to the correct VM and Services.